# Server crash randomly

Tags: kernel, crash, docker, ubuntu-minimal, dotnet

My Ubuntu Xenial (and also another Bionic Beaver one) server keeps crashing on random intervals. Sometimes twice a day and sometimes after 2 weeks and after months even!

I contacted my server hosting support and where able to connect to the server using KVM Tools. I was able to take the following screenshot.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/15WQDo1hR4HJEYXatzF4fJfzeug4YeKx0/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there's two posibilities here, the PSU is not providing enough power to the CPU or the CPU is being overclocked.

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2205211&p=12996968#post12996968

Basically your hosting provider is being irresponsible with their machines.

I'd recomend letting them know about the hardware fault and suggesting they stop overclocking and change the power supply for the server rack containing your ubuntu.

or just switch hosting service.

Comment: I think I would be more confindent when talking with them if I have evident logs. I did not read the link you have provided and I will now. Please, let me know what sorts of logs I can open so I can confirm.

Comment: I don't know actually. you can begin by what you have onscreen.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will do a search and report back here.

Comment: I have contacted the hosting provider and they did a hardware check and everything is working fine since then. Thanks.